# How to set command timeout for entity objectcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, command-timeout

I have a repository file in which we have created object context of entity type and not of `ObjectContext` class type

```
public class ShopRepository : GenericRepository<tbl_Shop>
{
        // Entity Framework context to the database
        private DBEntities _contextObject;

        public ShopRepository(DBEntities context)
            : base(context)
        {
            this._contextObject = context;
        }
}
```

I need to set command timeout property.
Can someone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to the `DbContext` command timeout through the `CommandTimeout` property of your `ObjectContext` like below:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout
```

So if you want to set it in your `ShopRepository` ctor just do this:

```
public ShopRepository(DBEntities context)
        : base(context)
{
     ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = your_value_here;
     this._contextObject = context;
}
```